# I want to use cocos2d-iphone 2.0 to draw a line

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i want to draw a line just like the rubber band to shot the bird in angrybird!
i use the code below ,but nothing show ,i am a newbie

```
-(void)draw
{
    glLineWidth(10.0f);
    GLfloat ver[4] = {_startPoint1.x,_startPoint1.y,_endPoint.x,_endPoint.y};
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ver);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
     ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position|kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color);

}
```

Comment: the cocos2d-iphone use the opengl es 2.0 ,not 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - (void) draw {
>
>   glLineWidth(2.0f); // 设置线宽
>     glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // 设置颜色
>     glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH); //把线段反锯齿
>
>   glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
>     glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
>     glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
>
>   GLfloat ver[4] = {_startPoint1.x, _startPoint1.y,
>        _endPoint.x, _endPoint.y};
>     glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, ver);
>     glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
>
>   GLfloat ver2[5] = {_startPoint2.x, _startPoint2.y,
>       _endPoint.x, _endPoint.y};
>     glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, ver2);
>     glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
>
>   glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
>     glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
>     glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
>
>   glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
>     }

Answer (score 1):

You could use the builtin drawing functions provided by cocos2d by calling them in the visit function.

```
#import "CCDrawingPrimitives.h"


-(void) visit{

    [super visit];
    ccDrawLine(ccp(0,100), ccp(320,150));
}
```

Check how to draw smooth line using this good [tutorial](http://merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/)

Comment: maybe i should use opengl,because the line is always change and like the real rubber bend to have elasticity

Comment: i have try to use the code in function visit ,but it doesnt work ,i think maybe there are some fault in my opengl code ,because i no nothing about opengl